# Chunked uploading of media with Twitter4J

Tags: java, twitter4j

I am trying to upload a video on Twitter. I am using the following code:

```
private UploadedMedia uploadMediaChunkedInit(long size) throws TwitterException {
    return new UploadedMedia(post(
        conf.getUploadBaseURL() + "media/upload.json",
        new HttpParameter[] { new HttpParameter("command", CHUNKED_INIT),
        new HttpParameter("media_type", "video/mp4"),
        new HttpParameter("total_bytes", size) }).asJSONObject());
}
```

Where I am getting following error:

> Method post is not defined

I got this code from here:

https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/pull/226/commits/73b43c1ae4511d3712118f61f983bcbca4ef0c59

Answer (score 0):

Those methods are private implementation details/utilities of the `TwitterImpl` class.

See lines [1844-1860](https://github.com/dk8996/twitter4j/blob/73b43c1ae4511d3712118f61f983bcbca4ef0c59/twitter4j-core/src/main/java/twitter4j/TwitterImpl.java#L1844-L1860) and lines [1862-1878](https://github.com/dk8996/twitter4j/blob/73b43c1ae4511d3712118f61f983bcbca4ef0c59/twitter4j-core/src/main/java/twitter4j/TwitterImpl.java#L1862-L1878)
(notice they are `private`).

You are approaching this incorrectly. Never should you have to call an internal implementation detail. Instead, use the public API of Twitter4J. You should use the `uploadMediaChunked` method instead. There is currently no javadoc I can link you to (since it's a relatively new feature).

I also see that this feature is not yet released. For now, you can build Twitter4J yourself and then use its public API (instead of copying source code into your own project).